# SQL Column with results from a year and other column with results from another year

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, report

There is been some time since I use SQL so I may be stacked in something really easy but here it goes:

Ill show you my dataset through example data: I have a query joining sales, products and customers. It seems like this:

```
customer_type | region | product_name | date       | sale_value
smallstore    | north  | chair        | 2016-01-01 | 22482
mediumstore   | south  | table        | 2016-02-02 | 50582
bigstore      | east   | desktop      | 2016-02-02 | 83737
smallstore    | north  | chair        | 2015-01-01 | 23828
mediumstore   | south  | coach        | 2015-02-02 | 93833
bigstore      | east   | desktop      | 2015-02-02 | 83282
```

the query would look like this:

```
select 
c.customer_type,
c.region,
p.product_name,
s.date,
sum(s.sale_value)
from
sales s 
inner join products p on p.id = s.product_id
inner join customers c on c.id = s.customer_id
group by c.customer_type, c.region, p.product_name, s.date,
```

I need to get the next result:

```
customer_type | region | product_name | date       | sales2015 | sales2016
smallstore    | north  | chair        | 2015-01-01 | 23828     | 22482
mediumstore   | south  | table        | 2016-02-02 | 0         | 50582
mediumstore   | south  | coach        | 2015-02-02 | 93833     | 0
bigstore      | east   | desktop      | 2015-02-02 | 83282     | 83737
```

So in words: I need to get for each customer_type, region, and product_name, its sales in 2015 compared with 2016.

How can I change the query to get that? I have tried different variations of subqueries of the form

```
select
c.customer_type,
c.region,
p.product_name,
s.date,
( select sum(sale_value) from ... where date between 2015-01-01 and 2015-12-31 group by ...) as sales2015,
( select sum(sale_value) from ... where date between 2016-01-01 and 2016-12-31 group by ...) as sales2016,
from
sales s 
inner join products p on p.id = s.product_id
inner join customers c on c.id = s.customer_id
group by c.customer_type, c.region, p.product_name, s.date,
```

But I'm getting cross products between the selects because there is no id to join subqueries with the main query. I also don't know how to manage the missing values in one year or the other.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't see the column `sales` in your table.

Comment: It is `sale_value`. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the subqueries, you can use:

```
...
sum(iif(year(date)=2015,sale_value,0)) as sales2015,
sum(iif(year(date)=2016,sale_value,0)) as sales2016,
...
```

Also, you should remove s.date from the select and the group by.

Comment: If using SQL Server 2008, or below, you'll need a [case expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) instead.  `... SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Date) =  THEN Sales_Value ELSE 0 END) AS Sales2016 ...`.  If you need more help the technique used is called a [cross tab](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172756(v=sql.80).aspx).

Comment: Tank you so much @CrimsonKing for your help. As destination-data said, my sql version didn't support the iff. Not sure why because it didn't marked error on the iff but on the condition. However, I used the CASE and it worked without problems.

Comment: Thank you as well for the cross tab reference @destination-data, I just didn't know how to search for it.